# Python ScriptEngine null on docker image

Tags: python, docker, spring-boot, java-8, jython

I have a normal spring boot app deployed on docker. The ScriptEngine works properly if app started normally or deployed on tomcat. But if I start it on docker the scriptEngine instance is returned null. Any idea?

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("python");  // returns null
```

Comment: what is the java version inside the docker image?

Comment: Openjdk 8 in docker.

Comment: did you tried to run the app normally with openjdk 8?

Comment: yes, the app works fine normally with openjdk. Also, it works fine with javascript scripts, just does not work with python

Comment: it's jython.jar in the docker image classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the jython library needs to be unpacked for docker from the spring boot application. Following configuration in maven makes it work on docker as well.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <requiresUnpack>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.python</groupId>
                <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </requiresUnpack>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I had the same issue when just trying to run from the jar built by maven. This unpack configuration worked perfectly for that. I see on the Spring Docs that it's used for unpacking "fat jars".

How did you know that `jython-standalone` was a fat jar that needed unpacked? I'm trying to make sure I understand in case it happens in the future a it's not clear to me which jars need unpacked.